# Feed error: A feed could not be found at youtube.com/... (1 post)

Tags: rss, youtube, feed

FeedWordPress doesn't work very well with YouTube feeds. The RSS feed clearly exists when I visit the link via web browser, but FeedWordPress can't find it.

YouTube feeds work just fine with other syndication scripts, so I imagine there must be some kind of solution for this.

If you don't have a specific answer, I would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Any thoughts.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedwordpress/

Answer (score 0):

even i have faced this prob and i again changed the plugin and added another addon to the wordpress to over come this issue . you can try this http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-feed-customizer/ its working

Thanks 
doodleblue